# try/catch/finally masks Jenkinsfile problems in case of groovy compiler exceptions

Tags: groovy, jenkins-workflow, jenkins-pipeline

I have code similar to the one below in my Jenkinsfile:

```
node {
   checkout scm
   // do some stuff
   try {
       // do some maven magic
   } catch (error) {
       stage "Cleanup after fail"
       emailext attachLog: true, body: "Build failed (see ${env.BUILD_URL}): ${error}", subject: "[JENKINS] ${env.JOB_NAME} failed", to: 'someone@example.com'
       throw error
   } finally {
       step $class: 'JUnitResultArchiver', testResults: '**/TEST-*.xml'
   }
}
```

If the above code fails because of some jenkins-pipeline related errors in the `try { }` (e.g. using unapproved static method) the script fails silently. When I remove the try/catch/finally I can see the errors.
Am I doing something wrong? Shouldn't rethrowing `error` make the pipeline errors appear in the log?

EDIT:
I've managed to nail down the problem to groovy syntax, when e.g. I use a variable that hasn't been assigned yet.
Example:

`echo foo`

If `foo` is not declared/assigned anywhere Jenkins will fail the build and won't show the reason if it is inside the try/catch/finally which rethrows the exception.

Comment: If this were plain Groovy, yes, it would've worked, but because this is a Groovy DSL, the DSL runner can do whatever it wants with the exception... Maybe you should try this instead: https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#code-error-code-error-signal

Comment: @RenatoBut https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#code-catcherror-code-catch-error-and-set-build-result Suggests that try/catch/finally should work also

Comment: Right, but if you have this problem looks like it doesn't...

Comment: Have you managed to solve this problem? I have exactly the same issue and I wasn't able to come up with some code that keeps the build results form inside the try block.

Comment: how do you get the shell error output from the try block into a variable.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42786894/store-the-console-output-of-a-build-step-execution-in-jenkins-pipeline

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42828546/106402

Answer (score 9):

This happens when an additional exception is thrown inside the `finally` block or before the re-throw inside `catch`. In these cases the `RejectedAccessException` is swallowed and `script-security` does not catch it.

Comment: No exception is thrown inside finally, because it works correctly when I remove the offending line in the try block.

Comment: Then it must be before the re-throw inside catch.

Comment: Nope, easily reproducible if the groovy script uses e.g. an undeclared variable. There is no exception stack trace, when I remove try/catch/finally I get the stacktrace.

Comment: Offhand it sounds like a bug. If there is a minimal reproducible test case, please file it as such.