# Store the console output of a build step execution in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: shell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

In my jenkins pipeline i use the "Execute shell command " to run my gradle build script.
Now i want to check if the build has failed in which case i would like to read the console output, store it in a string and publish it to a slack channel. 
The code that i have tried goes as follows :

```
try {
    for (int i = 0 ; i < noOfComponents ; i++ ){
        component = compileProjectsWithPriority[i]
        node {       
            out = sh script: "cd /home/jenkins/projects/${component} && ${gradleHome}/bin/gradle build", returnStdout: true}
    }
}
catch (e){
    def errorSummary = 'Build failed due to compilation error in '+"${component}"+'\n'+"${out}"
    slackSend (channel: '#my_channel', color: '#FF0000', message: errorSummary)
}
```

However it does not even execute the shell script and also the console output is null. What is the right approach to do this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks generally fine, and it works for me. You'd need to post more of your Jenkinsfile and the build output.

Comment: @ChristopherOrr "Build failed due to compilation error in test-service
null" . This is the message that i get on slack channel. What is the version of pipeline plugin that you using? mine is 2.4

Comment: Whatever the latest version is. You can try adding `def component` and `def out` before `try`, but it should work anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The [`sh`](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#sh-shell-script) command in Jenkins pipelines may not work with shell built-ins like `cd`. Perhaps try using [`dir`](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#dir-change-current-directory), as below:

```
node {
    dir("/home/jenkins/projects/${component}") {
        out = sh script: "${gradleHome}/bin/gradle build", returnStdout: true
    }
}
```

All commands within `{` and `}` for a `dir` will execute with the specified directory as their working directory. This will overcome any problems that may exist with the `cd` shell built-in.