# How to avoid that Jenkins reuses a workspace?

Tags: jenkins

I have several parallel stages that share a node, and clean up their workspace after they are done. The issue I have is that when the stage fails, I want the workspace NOT cleaned up, so I can inspect it.

What happens instead is:

1. failing stage fails, leaves the workspace as I want it
2. second stage reuses the workspace, succeeds
3. second stage cleans up the workspace

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

Jenkins has a post-stage for this. Depending on the result of your pipeline a different branch of code is executed. So lets say your pipeline is successful then your cleanup script of clean up plugin is called. If you pipeline fails you can archive your results or simply skip the cleanup of the workspace.

Check the official jenkin documentation for more information (search for 'post'): https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('PostExample') {
            steps {
                // do something here
            }
        }
    }
    post { //Is called after your stage
        failure { 
            //pipeline failed - do not clear workspace
        }
        success {
            //pipeline is successful - clear workspace
        }
    }
}
```

On the other hand if you want to keep your results you could think about archiving them so they are independent from your workspace because you can access them anytime from the jenkins gui (

Comment: I think I need to rephrase the question. The workspace should not be used at all by the second stage, so it also doesn't overwrite anything. The question is even slightly wrong, the cleanup happens at the start of the stage AND at the end of the stage, to avoid building something in a workspace with unknown state and potentially wrong stuff lying around.

Answer (score 0):

you just have to use finally(this will execute irrespective of stage output) method while you are executing jenkins files: Refer to [How to perform actions for failed builds in Jenkinsfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36837683/how-to-perform-actions-for-failed-builds-in-jenkinsfile)

Answer (score 0):

You should look for the `ws(specified_workspace){your actions}` which helps you redefine the workspace of the contained actions, so you can put it in the beginning of the pipeline. You can create a new workspace for each new execution of the pipeline (for example with the execution number or with the date). And in your post actions (`post` for declarative and `finally` for scripted), you execute a bat or shell command that deletes the whole folder in case of success.

There's also the possibility to use artifacts and archive your workspace in case of failure